# Как использовать boost::multiprecision для округление длинного float?

Tags: boost, c++

Как присвоить переменной некоторую часть числа `e` (к примеру `e = 2.718281828459045235360287471352`) с помощью инструментов `boost` и округлить с точностью до 7-го знака. Для подобных задач в первые прибегаю к `boost`, мне кажется с ним это легче будет сделать, чем мудрить длинную арифметику стандартной библиотекой `C++`.

Начал строить приложение по следующему сценарию:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/mpfr.hpp>

namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;    
typedef mp::number<mp::mpfr_float_backend<300>>  my_float;

int main()
{  
    my_float a = 2.718281828459045235360287471352;
    ???
    return 0;
}
```

На этом к сожалению все - не знаю как продолжить?

И почему при вызове:

```
std::cout << a;
```

выводится только часть числа?:

> 2.71828

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

#include <boost/multiprecision/mpfr.hpp>
#include <boost/math/constants/constants.hpp>

int main()
{
    namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;
    using mpfr_300 = mp::number<mp::mpfr_float_backend<300u> >;
    using mpfr_7 = mp::number<mp::mpfr_float_backend<7u> >;

    mpfr_300 e = boost::math::constants::e<mpfr_300>();
    std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<mpfr_300>::digits10) << e << std::endl;

    mpfr_7 e_truncated{e};
    std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<mpfr_7>::digits10) << e_truncated << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```